# Problems with using Regex but don't know why

Tags: c#, regex

so i am making an WPF application where you insert PDF files and it will convert to text, after that a few Regex functions will be used on the text to give me only the important parts of the pdf.

the first problem i am running into is with numbers, if the number for example is 6.90 it will come out as 6.9. I have tried changing my Regex but it wont make a difference.

the second problem i have is when with dates for example 09-06-2022 it just wont write anything i have also tried changing the Regex but it just wont show up.

anyone know why this is ?

> this is a line in the PDF i use i am trying to only get 6.90

`Date:  06-09-2022 € 5.70 € 1.20 € 6.90`

> this is the Regex is use to only get the Amount

`(?<=Date\:?\s?\s?\s?\d{0,2}\-\d{0,2}\-\d{0,4}\s?\€\s\d{0,10}\.?\,?\d{0,2}\s?\€\s\d{0,10}\,?\.?\d{0,10}\s?\€\s)\d{0,10}\.\d{0,2}`

> this is the Regex i use to only get the Date

`(?<=Date\:?\s?\s?\s?)\d{0,2}\-\d{0,2}\-\d{0,4}`

There are a lot of "?" in it because i have to make it compatible to multiple different PDF

[screenshot of the outcome for the number in my selfmade Regex executor application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bflal.png)

[screenshot of the outcome for the date in my selfmade Regex executor application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtROc.png)

[screenshot of the outcome i get when i inserted a PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPg8T.png)

as you can see in the screenshots for some reason i get different results and i have no clue why its different

> MainWindow

> *the button does all the work for recieving the pdf and changing it to text and going thru the correct class where all the regex are.*

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
//ItextSharp is a tool i use in Visual Studio


public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
  private List<IRegexPDFFactuur> _listRegexFactuur = new 
  List<IRegexPDFFactuur>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
  public void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
           if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                tbInvoer.Text = "";
                var file = openFileDialog.FileName;
                var text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                PdfReader pdf_Reader = new PdfReader(file);
                String tempPDFText = "";
                for (int i = 1; i <= pdf_Reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {

                    tempPDFText = tempPDFText + 
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdf_Reader, i);
                    
                }
                var PDFText = tempPDFText;
                _listRegexFactuur.Add(new PDFtest1Type());

                foreach (var tempRegexFactuurType in _listRegexFactuur)
                {
                    if 
(tempRegexFactuurType.IsRegexTypeValidForPDF(PDFText))
                    {
                        var tempPDFdate = tempRegexFactuurType.GetPDFdate(PDFText);
                        var tempTotalamount = tempRegexFactuurType.GetTotalamount(PDFText);

                        tbInvoer.Text += $"PDF Date: {tempPDFdate}\r\n";
                        
                        tbInvoer.Text += $"Total amount: {tempTotalamount}";

                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
}
```

> Interface for Regex

```
string regexPDFname { get; set; }

string regexPDFdate { get; set; }

string regexTotalamount { get; set; }


bool IsRegexTypeValidForPDF(string argInput);

double? GetPDFdate(string argInput);

double? GetTotalamount(string argInput);
```

> Class with implemented Interface for Regex

```
public string regexPDFname { get; set; } = @"(PDFtest1)";

public string regexPDFdate { get; set; } = @"(?<=Date\:?\s?\s?\s?)\d{0,2}\-\d{0,2}\-\d{0,4}";

public string regexTotalamount { get; set; } = @"(?<=Date\:?\s?\s?\s?\d{0,2}\-\d{0,2}\-\d{0,4}\s?\€\s\d{0,10}\.?\,?\d{0,2}\s?\€\s\d{0,10}\,?\.?\d{0,10}\s?\€\s)\d{0,10}\.\d{0,2}"



public bool IsRegexTypeValidForPDF(string argInput)
        {
            var tempMatch = Regex.Match(argInput, regexPDFname, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (!tempMatch.Success) return false;

            if (tempMatch.Value == "PDFtest1") return true;
            else return false;
        }


public double? GetPDFdate(string argInput)
        {
            var tempMatch = Regex.Match(argInput, regexPDFdate, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (!tempMatch.Success) return null;

            if (Double.TryParse(tempMatch.Value, out var tempPDFdate)) return tempPDFdate;
            else return null;
        }


public double? GetTotalamount(string argInput)
        {
            var tempMatch = Regex.Match(argInput, regexTotalamount, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (!tempMatch.Success) return null;

            if (Double.TryParse(tempMatch.Value, out var tempTotalamount)) return tempTotalamount;
            else return null;
        }
```

Comment: "6.90 it will come out as 6.9" what data type holds the value? Any numerical type will remove unnecessary zeros, this is by design.

Comment: @gunr2171 what do you mean by this i don't understand, what are you asking with "what data type holds the value?" i am guessing that you mean that this number is from a int or var in the code itself but its inserted from a PDF. i made another application that turns all kinds of pdf in text almost the same as if you would select everything in a pdf and paste it in a notepad. Maybe i didn't explain enough but when i take "Date:  06-09-2022 € 5.70 € 1.20 € 6.90" i use Regex to only get 6.90 but what i get is 6.9.

Comment: I removed the escaping of the euro sign, but then it matches the number right? See https://regex101.com/r/aLvBLh/1 But if you want number of the last euro sign, you can also use a capture group `Date:\s.*€\s(\d+(?:\.\d+))?\b` https://regex101.com/r/d7f9Wb/1

Comment: @AliExpresz See the first comment of gunr2171, what is the datatype that is giving you the result of 6.9?

Comment: @Thefourthbird i understand what he was asking now. the outcome of what i receive are all strings because numbers are not the only thing i am trying to get out out of those pdf's. also the 2 regex you gave me, the first one gives me 6.9 and the second does not give me anything.

Comment: i have edited the question and added some screenshots so it maybe becomes a bit clearer.

Comment: @AliExpresz Can you add the relevant code to the question handling the pdf with the regex?

Comment: @Thefourthbird i added the parts of the code for this question

Comment: You are using `Double.TryParse` in the `GetTotalamount` method, I think you can check if the parsing was successful, and then return `tempMatch` instead of `tempTotalamount`

Comment: @Thefourthbird i cant return `tempMatch`.

Comment: You can get the value from the regex match and let the function return a string.

Comment: @Thefourthbird i don't understand can you explain please?

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier without Regex

```
            string input = "Date:  06-09-2022 € 5.70 € 1.20 € 6.90";
            string[] array = input.Split(new char[] {':', '€'});
            DateTime date  = DateTime.Parse(array[1]);
            decimal amount1 = decimal.Parse(array[2]);
            decimal amount2 = decimal.Parse(array[3]);
            decimal amount3 = decimal.Parse(array[4]);
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem with this is your string input is just one of the 100 lines in a PDF as i said i am inserting a whole PDF and different kinds also the date and the amount are not the only thing i am getting out of the PDF. so if i wanted to do it this way it would take me a long time to change everything.

Comment: Use Regex to extract the lines.  The parse data with code above.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use Regex, this is a much simpler solution

```
Date\:\s{0,}(\d{1,2}-?\d{1,2}-?\d{2,4}).+(\d+\.\d+).+(\d+\.\d+).+(\d+\.\d+)
```

### Breakdown

---

`Date\:\s{0,}` matches Date: followed by 0 or more spaces

`(\d{1,2}-?\d{1,2}-?\d{2,4})` matches your date string accepting 1 or 2 numbers for month and day and 2 or 4 for year

`.+(\d+\.\d+)` matches any characters until it matches 1 or more numbers followed by . and 1 or more numbers. This is repeated 3 times to obtain the currency values

[RegEx Storm Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Date%5c%3a%5cs%7b0%2c%7d%28%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d-%3f%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d-%3f%5cd%7b2%7d%28%3f%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%29%3f%29.%2b%28%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%29.%2b%28%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%29.%2b%28%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%29&i=Date%3a++06-09-2022+%e2%82%ac+5.70+%e2%82%ac+1.20+%e2%82%ac+6.90%0d%0aDate%3a+9-6-2022+%e2%82%ac+5.70+%e2%82%ac+1.20+%e2%82%ac+6.90%0d%0aDate%3a09-06-22+%e2%82%ac+5.70+%e2%82%ac+1.20+%e2%82%ac+6.90)